# Jquery with ajax controls

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Below is the offending piece of java script code(1). I am using an ajax update panel with a ajax calender control and an asp button(2). We are using the javascript to simulate a button click. Which is in conflict with the calender control and the update panel. The error is (3)

```
    function tsSave() {
        $("#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click();
    }

 <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="calRemovalDate" runat="server"  PopupButtonID="img1" PopupPosition="Right" TargetControlID="txtRemovalDate">
                                </ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

(3)

> The Controls collection cannot be
>   modified because the control contains
>   code blocks

I understand that there are better ways of doing this, but this is the method we required to use. If there is a way using jquery without using the  '=' to still grab the clientID of the submit button that would probably fix the problem, as always thank you for your help

Comment: tsSave exists outside of update panel <script = 'text/javascript'> tsSave()</script><body><updatePanel> ...

Answer (score 1):

Move the

```
function tsSave() { 
        $("#<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click(); 
    }
```

outside of the update panel. If it can't be moved for some reason, put a snippet of JS outside the panel that has `<%=btnSave.ClientID%>` set in it and call that from your JS in the update panel.

Comment: I am sorry i should've stated that the function tsSave() is already outside of the update panel

Comment: If you just include a literal string in `tsSave()` instead of `"<%=btnSave.ClientID%>"` do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was just not to use jquery with this particle issue.